# Stuck in regular expression

Tags: java, android, regex

I have 3 strings that contain 2 fields and 2 values per string. I need a regular expression for the strings so I can get the data. Here are the 3 strings:

```
TTextRecordByLanguage{Text=Enter here the amount to transfer from your compulsory book saving account to your compulsory checking account; Id=55; }

TTextRecordByLanguage{Text=Hello World, CaribPayActivity!; Id=2; }

TTextRecordByLanguage{Text=(iphone); Id=4; }
```

The 2 fields are `Text` and `Id`, so I need an expression that gets the data between the `Text` field and the semi-colon (`;`). Make sure special symbols and any data are included.

**Update ::**

What i have tried.....

```
Pattern pinPattern = Pattern.compile("Text=([a-zA-Z0-9 \\E]*);");
                        ArrayList<String> pins = new ArrayList<String>();
                        Matcher m = pinPattern.matcher(soapObject.toString());
                        while (m.find()) {
                            pins.add(m.group(1));
                            s[i] = m.group(1);
                            
                        }
                        Log.i("TAG", "ARRAY=>"+ s[i]);
```

Comment: @user1381267: What is the purpose of your `\\E`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a RE like this:

```
Text=.*?;
```

e.g: a returned of the last string should be

> Text=(iphone);

then you may eliminate **Text=** and **;** out of string as you want the content only.

Comment: Expanding on jaselg's answer, you can use `Text=(.*?)` and get `group(1)`.